# Subsite navigation changed, how to reach the site and fix the link

Tags: navigation, hyperlink, workspace, 2007

I have a working site:

```
http://moss/culture/
```

The culture site collection has a subsite (icon show it to be a workspace) that still shows up in the Current Navigation, SharePoint Designer and the Sites and Workspaces listing.  However the link is very wrong, and I cannot access the site.

It used to be

```
http://moss/culture/par/
```

But the site owner did something in the Site Navigation Settings (he says) that broke the link and the /culture/ site reports the link as

```
http://moss/culture/viewlst.aspx/default.aspx
```

Which give a 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR warning.  None of the content listed in the Site Hierachry treeview is accessible.  It all throws this same error regardless of the link.

I cannot access the site with any of the [administrative functions](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/sp07urls.aspx), but they all give the same error.

My suspicion is while trying to rename the site, the cut and paste the wrong thing into the wrong box, but I just don't know where to look next.

**NEW INFO**
I am now a site collection admin.  I enabled the Publishing feature and I cannot access the Manage Content and Structure page.  Unknown error.

Still looking for settings to reset on the parent site.

Answer (score 2):

What happen if you type these .aspx pages directly to the link?  (the original and the changed one)

/_layouts/settings.aspx

/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx

/_layouts/prjsetng.aspx, and so on...

Can  "?contents=1" show webparts inside? But I`m not sure if it helps for workspaces.

[edit] I`m sorry, you already mentioned these links above by link "administrative functions".

Comment: Same 500 error.

Comment: I`m sorry, you mentioned it above by link "administrative functions". And what about change the path in designer ? Or move workspace to another location or create some new page and promote it as default.aspx

Comment: Can't move the site or access it all in Designer.  Still awaiting for a site collection admin to see if those permissions help.